# make keeps going on multi job build

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

We have a bigger build on a Linux system
in some cases, the build fails if parallel jobs are used.
Upgrading to make 4.3 reduced the number of these problems happening
but now the main issue is, the make call does not stop after the build error.
we use the call:
`make --jobs=3 -f Makefile`
The build errors are:

```
error   30-May-2023 11:14:14    Fatal error: can't create linux64/BoundaryConditionServer.o: No such file or directory
error   30-May-2023 11:14:14    Assembler messages:
error   30-May-2023 11:14:14    Fatal error: can't create linux64/BcsCollect.o: No such file or directory
build   30-May-2023 11:14:14    g++ -c -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wpointer-arith -Wno-switch -std=c++17 -ffor-scope -pipe -fno-gnu-keywords -foperator-names -pthread -Wno-long-long -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers  -O3    <<removed text>>
build   30-May-2023 11:14:15    g++ -c -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wpointer-arith -Wno-switch -std=c++17 -ffor-scope -pipe -fno-gnu-keywords -foperator-names -pthread -Wno-long-long -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers  -O3  <<removed text>>
error   30-May-2023 11:14:16    make[1]: *** [Makefile:18: linux64/BcsCollect.o] Error 2
error   30-May-2023 11:14:16    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
error   30-May-2023 11:14:19    make[1]: *** [Makefile:21: linux64/BoundaryConditionServer.o] Error 2
```

shouldn't the build abort and make a return with some error code?
It runs inside a script on a buildserver, the return code is always success
(this complicates finding the main culprit because the build fails several steps later)

Question is:
isn't stopping after an error the default behaviour?
Do I need to do some special handling if using a multi-job run?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question but I believe `make -j` will eventually stop after an error. however it will not terminate jobs that have already started. I did a quick check on make 4.4 (Fedora) and it did return an error code in `$?` if one of the tasks failed

Comment: When a command fails, the instance of make where it failed will not start any new commands: it will wait for the commands already running to finish, then it will exit with an error.  If your build system uses recursive make, then _other_ instances of make (in other directories for example) can't know that _this_ instance of make failed, and so they will continue to run until they exit (or one of their commands fails).  Only the parent make knows of the failure, so it won't invoke any more sub-makes.  Etc.

Comment: Note well that although parallel `make` can really speed up your builds, it relies on you to be much more careful about specifying the prerequisites for your rules.  It may bite you if you have been lazy or relied on undocumented behavior.  An especial source of issues is relying on the order of your prerequisite lists to control the order in which those prerequisites are built.  You can often get away with that for serial builds, but it is not safe to rely on such ordering in parallel builds.

Comment: I think it is related to using a loop in the make file, which was done to explicitly continue the build even if there is an error.
We are going to have some internal discussion on how to proceed here.